# Checking out tags on Git

Tags: git, git-tag

I was going through some git internals and came across tags and how they're stored internally. In the [Git SCM site](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) I found the following:

> #### Checking out Tags
>
> You can’t really checkout a tag in Git, since they can’t be moved
>   around. If you want to put a version of your repository in your
>   working directory that looks like a specific tag, you can create a new
>   branch at a specific tag with git checkout -b [branchname] [tagname]:
>
> `git checkout -b version2 v2.0.0`
>
> Switched to a new branch 'version2'
>
> Of course if you do this and do a commit, your version2 branch will be
>   slightly different than your v2.0.0 tag since it will move forward
>   with your new changes, so do be careful.

I have the following doubts:

1. Why can't we check out tags? Can't we traverse the Git TAG to make `HEAD` point to the commit pointed to by the tag?
2. Can we create a new commit which will then point to the commit
   pointed to by tag as the parent?
3. It is said that if we create a new branch from the tag and commit, it'll be slightly different. What difference are they talking about? Won't the new commit (assuming nothing has changed) refer to the tagged commit as its parent with everything else (trees & blobs) remaining the same?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I'm referring to cases where HEAD and the tag point to different commits.

Comment: It says that after a commit the branch and the tag won't point to the same thing. That's the "slight difference".

Comment: Oh, they were talking about the branch being a pointer and not the current state of the repo. That makes more sense.

Comment: Read here how to checkout tags, wont answer 2&3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/how-to-checkout-remote-git-tag/35979751#35979751

Comment: @CodeWizard If I checkout a tag without a branch name, will it create a new branch with name as the tag or will it create a detached HEAD situation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324143/git-check-out-a-tag-modify-something-then-tag-it-again)?

Comment: it should create detached HEAD which you can read more about it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716 but if you are on the same commit as the tag (HEAD==TAG) it should not be in detached HEAD since its the latest commit and it will be just like you are checking out HEAD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't we check out tags?

We *can!*

> Can't we traverse the Git TAG to make HEAD point to the commit pointed to by the tag?

Yes, we can do just that (though, strictly speaking, we don't even need much if any traversal: commits are snapshots, so we're done once we reach the right one, and tags generally require either zero or one intermediate steps to reach the commit).

The more typical state for the `HEAD` file—which is an actual file in `.git` named `HEAD`—is that it contains the *name of a branch*, rather than the *ID of a commit*.  This mode does not have much of a formal name, but I call it "being on a branch", to contrast it with the other mode.

The mode we get when `.git/HEAD` points directly to some commit (by containing its hash ID) is, [as CodeWizard mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903176/checking-out-tags-on-git#comment76784261_44903176), called a "detached HEAD".  Since `.git/HEAD` no longer contains the name of a branch, we are now on *no* branch—or, equivalently, on some sort of unnamed branch, where we can use the `@` symbol (since Git version 1.8.5) to name it, or by spelling out the word `HEAD`.  Of course `HEAD` is a fine name; it's just that Git will overwrite the contents of the `.git/HEAD` file as soon as we run `git checkout master` again, for instance, and then we will no longer have the hash ID stored anywhere.

> Can we create a new commit which will then point to the commit pointed to by tag as the parent?

English is a bit ambiguous here, but I think a diagram makes it clearer that the answer is "yes":

```
 initially: on branch `master` with commit `H` as the current commit

 ...--F--G     <-- tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, commit `H` points back to commit `G`; commit `G` points to commit `F`; and so on.  The branch named `master` points to commit `H`, and the tag name `v2.0.0` points to commit `G` (either directly, if it's a lightweight tag, or through one *annotated tag object*, if it's an annotated tag).

```
 After `git checkout v2.0.0`:

 ...--F--G     <-- HEAD, tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master
```

The `.git/HEAD` file now contains the hash ID of commit `G`.

```
If we make a new commit now:

           I   <-- HEAD
          /
 ...--F--G     <-- tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master
```

New commit `I` has commit `G` as its parent, as you suggested.  The `.git/HEAD` file now contains the hash ID of commit `I`.

> It is said that if we create a new branch from the tag and commit, it'll be slightly different. What difference are they talking about? Won't the new commit (assuming nothing has changed) refer to the tagged commit as its parent with everything else (trees & blobs) remaining the same?

The *commit contents* would be identical, but the *drawing of the commit graph* would change a bit.  Here's the new graph drawings, starting from the same starting point, but using `git checkout -b version2 v2.0.0` as the middle step.

```
 initially: on branch `master` with commit `H` as the current commit

 ...--F--G     <-- tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master (HEAD)


 After `git checkout -b version2 v2.0.0`:

 ...--F--G     <-- version2 (HEAD), tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master


If we make a new commit now:

           I   <-- version2 (HEAD)
          /
 ...--F--G     <-- tag: v2.0.0
          \
           H   <-- master
```

Note that in this case—the one where we are "on a branch" named `version2`—***the branch name moves along with us as we make new commits***.  When we are not on any branch, in the "detached HEAD" mode, new commits just update (the commit hash ID stored in) `.git/HEAD`.  But when `.git/HEAD` contains the *name of a branch*, those new commits *update that branch*.  The `.git/HEAD` file itself just continues to contain the name of the branch.

---

This, in fact, is what it means to be "on a branch": whenever `.git/HEAD` contains the *name of the branch*, various operations—specifically including making new commits and using `git reset`—change the *hash ID the branch name remembers*, rather than changing `.git/HEAD` itself.  Whenever `.git/HEAD` contains the *hash ID of a commit*, these same operations just update `.git/HEAD` itself.

The `git checkout` command usually updates the contents of `.git/HEAD`, and is one of the few commands that can change the *branch name* stored in `.git/HEAD`.  (I say "usually" here because `git checkout` is kind of a [kitchen-sink command](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everything_but_the_kitchen_sink), having various modes that do oddball things just because they're closely related to the main thing that it usually does.)  Specifically, if you are on a branch, `git checkout` can put you on a *different* branch; if you're not on any branch, `git checkout` can get you onto one; if you use `--detach` or a tag name or similar, `git checkout` can put you into detached HEAD mode; and if you're not on any branch, `git checkout` can change which commit `HEAD` points to.

(The `git reset` command can do some of these things, but it won't take you on or off any branch.  Like `git checkout`, it's a bit "kitchen sinky": it has many things it can do and it is hard to describe these well without many words and several diagrams!)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write a detailed reply. It really helped me piece together a lot of the internal details.